# Returning duplicate rows based on more than one column

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates

how do you return ALL rows when searching for duplicates in MySQL? You'll have to bear with me because I am not an expert on MySQL.

Here's an example.

DATA

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PlayerList` (
  `Team` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Player` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Games` int(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `PlayerList` (`Team`, `Player`, `Games`) VALUES
('Team1st', 'Geoff', 8),
('Team1st', 'John, 4),
('Team1st', 'Pete', 6),
('Team2nd', 'Dave', 6),
('Team2nd', 'Bill', 6),
('Team2nd', 'Darren', 6),
('Team2nd', 'Geoff', 4);
```

I run the below. To find instances where a player has played for more than one team.

```
SELECT * FROM `PlayerList` GROUP BY Player HAVING COUNT(Player) > 1
```

But this only returns one row as expected because of the group by clause (returns the first row).  I want to return both rows in the SQL results, but as you can't have a COUNT in a WHERE clause, I have no clue how to handle this situation.  I don't want to GROUP results together.  I just want to list all the lines that have a duplicate value in the player column.  Can this even be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by joining back to the results of your query:

```
SELECT pl.*
FROM PlayerList pl JOIN
     (SELECT Player
      FROM `PlayerList`
      GROUP BY Player
      HAVING COUNT(Player) > 1
     ) pp
     ON pl.Player = pp.Player;
```